# What was the space station structure in Clone Wars Season Six?

Tags: star-wars

In the first episode of Season Six of the Clone Wars, the planet under siege Ringo Vinda, is a planet encompassed by a giant ring space station. The entire planet!!! What type of megastructure would this be considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your asking if there's a word you would use for a very large structure that encompasses the planet.  I hate to disappoint you but I believe it's still considered a space station.  Just because it encompasses the entire planet doesn't change the fact that it is a space station, and I don't believe there is a specific word for a megastructure space station that encompasses an entire planet.

According to the some quick research I found the definition of Space Station on the Wikipedia and it describes it as :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_station

> A space station (or orbital station) is a spacecraft capable of
>   supporting a crew, which is designed to remain in space (most commonly
>   in low Earth orbit) for an extended period of time and for other
>   spacecraft to dock. A space station is distinguished from other
>   spacecraft used for human spaceflight by lack of major propulsion or
>   landing systems. Instead, other vehicles transport people and cargo to
>   and from the station.

I couldn't find anything referring to an extra large space station, also I found that the one you are talking about is just called a ring space station according to the wookieepedia as well..

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Unknown

> On a mission to relieve the ring space station in Ringo Vinda's orbit,
>   Jedi Knight Anakin Skywalker and twin Jedi Masters Tiplar and Tiplee
>   lead several clone trooper detachments against the occupying droid
>   force under Admiral Trench, among them are Clone captain Rex, ARC
>   Trooper Fives and clone trooper Tup.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree that this structure would be called just "space station". We can find similarly large megastructure called Citadel Station (not to be confused with Mass Effect Citadel) millennia earlier on the planet Telos IV and it is referred just as space station (see http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel_Station). 
If you were to be creative, you could call it something like "Ring Station" but that is not supported by any canon I know of, it's just my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Is it orbiting if it is then I would agree with the others that it is a space station others wise, if it isn't orbiting I have no other idea, except maybe a micro-dyson ring